# Angular JS fails to load and bind new data after curd operation

Tags: angularjs, spring, mongodb, rest

I have the problem that Angular JS fails to load and bind new data after curd operation. My program uses Angular JS, Spring REST service and MongoDB. I don't want to reload the page after any curd operation. I want to bind the refresh data with the particular controller that needed to change. It works when I use the load function.

Comment: Before we can "post our comments and solutions", it helps tremendously for you to share what you have tried so far. That way we can guide you through the issues you're having. As is this question is too vague and too broad for a Q&A format.

Comment: Please share your code